# If X is an infinite set with the discrete topology, which subsets of X are compact?

Tags: general-topology

I know that a discrete space is compact if and only if it is finite.

To answer the question, can I choose finite sets from X and endow it with the discrete topology? It then becomes a finite discrete space. I'm not so sure if this is correct or if it's what the question is asking! Any feedback would be helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only finite subsets of $X$ are compact.

Any finite set in any topological space is compact. Conversely, for any $S \subseteq X$, consider the open cover $(\{x\})_{x \in S}$

Comment: Okay, it makes sense! I don't need to consider subspaces. Thank you.